# ajax php beginner basic function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi I'm not really sure where to start with this, but I'm just looking to learn ajax and php, but am unsure what I'm missing here.

I want this code set up so that every time I click `.test-ajax` it increments a number, because I'm looking to learn how it works with php Im hoping to have the incrementing happening in a php file.

Here is my jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.test-ajax').live('click', function(event)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'variableplusone.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { offset: 2 },
            success: function(offset) {
                alert(offset);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and my `variableplusone.php` file...

```
<?php
$x = add_one();

function add_one()
{
    if (isset($_POST['offset']))
    {
        $offset = $offset;
        echo $offset;
    }
}

return $x;
```

Just wondering how to get the value of `$offset` to be affected in the php file, and then returned back and updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function add_one() {
    $offset = 0;
    if(isset($_POST['offset'])) {
        $offset = $_POST['offset'];
        $offset++;
    }

    return $offset;
}

$x = add_one();
die("$x");
```

Obviously, you need to check your $_POST['offset'] is a number and other sanity checks. To return the value to the javascript, it is enough to echo it, or die. In the javascript, you will receive one single value, which in your example would be 3 (you pass 2, and the PHP increments it by one).

EDIT: To "keep" the changes to the number, you have a choice: Either you remember it on the client side with javascript or cookies, or you remember it on the server side with a session variable.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    myVariable = 2;

    $('.test-ajax').live('click', function(event)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'variableplusone.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { offset: myVariable },
            success: function(offset) {
            alert(offset);
            myVariable = offset;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Above is one way to remember it on the client. Be aware that if the user refreshes the page, it is reset to the default (2).

Comment: I'd rather `echo` instead of `die`

Comment: @lethal-guitar Out of interest... why?

Comment: thanks but just wondering how do I get that new number saved so when I click again, it increments again, like, 3, 4, 5, etc

Comment: @Adrian - See edit to post. Probably not the best way to do it, because if the user refreshes the page you lose all the increments. If you need to keep the increments even if the user refreshes the page, possibly look at cookies or session variables.

Comment: Thanks for the help Gareth, client side is fine for now, but for some reason that doesnt seem to increment, is my variableplusone file ok? I have the code you have within the `add_one()` function. and the `return $x` after that.

Comment: @Adrian - try with the modifications I made to the PHP file. In your PHP file the function doesn't return anything, so $x remains null. In mine, $x takes the incremented value of $offset, and is then echo-ed to the javascript function. It returns 0 if the $_POST['offset'] is not set.

Comment: thanks Gareth, that worked great, just for understanding purposes, am I right in saying that I fed the `offset` variable into the php file, that function incremented it and the `die` kept the value of the function?

Comment: Not quite... the value is being kept by the "myVariable" variable in Javascript. We've set that to the default "2" when the page loads. We then pass that value via ajax to the PHP script, which increments it, and echoes it back to the javascript (you could replace "die" with "echo" and the script would still work). Then, in the javascript, we write the new offset back to the myVariable. It's like a question and a response: The question contains the url and the post data (offset=myVariable), and the response is myVariable + 1. This response is then saved to the myVariable.

Comment: @GarethL because the code's intention is clearer. To me, `die` is associated with "abort due to error". Which is not the case here. Therefore I'd rather use `echo ..; return 0;` to make it clear that this is intended to output a value, and not handling an error. All just personal preference, of course.

Comment: @lethal-guitar - OK, I see your point. Personally I use die when I want to guarantee that there can be no more output from the script, as it's one line of code instead of two, but again, this is just personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do `echo $x;` and then in success handler you'll have it in your `offset` variable.

Or if you insist on having some more complex structure, I would recommend taking a look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php and JSON request with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

your return $x doesnt make sense and your $x is empty anyways becuase your function doesnt return a value.
i think you want your function to return the $offset and then echo your $x in your php file. 
the output of your php file will be in the offset variable in your js - so in your case its the offset.

something like this

```
<?php
$x = add_one();

function add_one()
{
    if (isset($_POST['offset']))
    {
        return $_POST['offset']++;
    }
}

echo $x;
?>
```